# Roadmap to understand gerbe in the sense of Lurie’s Higher Topos Theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory, gerbes

> Definition $7.2.2.20$ : Let $\mathfrak{X} $ be an $\infty$-topos. An $n$-gerbe on $\mathfrak{X}$ is an object in $\mathfrak{X}$ which is $n$-connective and $n$-truncated.

Above is the definition of an $n$-gerbe in [Higher Topos Theory](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf). I want to understand this notion and further results. The reason I want to understand this is, this book is mentioned in an answer to [my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304571/cohomological-description-of-gerbes-over-stacks/309713#comment809178_309713).

Can some one kindly suggest a roadmap (with minimal material needed) to understand these. I do not prefer to read whole book at this point of time. So, roadmap for this particular purpose would be useful for me.

Comment: [Groth's survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2925) might be useful. (Also, you might want to skip (or skim) chapters 2, 3, and 4 of HTT when first approaching the material). On a different note, I am trying to write a guide to this stuff [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275964/textbooks-on-higher-category-theory). It is very far from being minimal, but you might find it useful (I hope). (At this point it is also really badly-written, and I am still learning the material, so you should take what is there with a grain of salt)

Comment: There is this too: [A learning roadmap for higher topos theory](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/2748/a-learning-roadmap-for-higher-topos-theory/)

Comment: @Emily thanks,,. I will see that ::